Spring Authorization Server - Possibility for extended features
While integrating Spring Authorization Server in my system for the oauth2 basic workflow, i found myself in potential situations regarding the future extensions for this.
Is any of the following feature possible to be integrated in the spring authorization server microservice?

Provide a way for users to register and then after automatically be logged in
Provide multi factor authentication/sms , etc.
Let users log by email and then by code from the email ( magic link / passwordless authentication )
Can the register endpoint be made in a way that user needs to verify the email?
Is there any way maybe from a spring cloud gateway client to generate another access or refresh token for the session after user changed it's firstName, lastName, etc ?

The dependency i'm using in my auth server is spring boot starter authorization server.

These are questions I had from the beginning of the Spring Authorization server project and because of which I believe that it is far behind - and will probably never reach - competitors (Keycloak, Auth0, ...), or at an incredibly high price (all the energy that is put into it isn't available for bug fixes and enhancements of existing OAuth2 clients & resource server features). Plus, most developpers hardly have an idea of what it takes to configure a client or a resource server properly, so, building an authorization server from ground up...

And for your last bullet point, I think you're somehow hitting this issue I reported some time ago: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/15509 (even if you trigger a refresh token flow, the Authentication in the security context won't be updated)

Yes, i tried to do it manually in the gateway but indeed, nothing was updating.
However, i noticed that spring cloud gateway with spring oauth2 client does it out of the blue now.
Did you manage to get the logout workflow going? Because for me it's not working and after logging out from gateway i also need to send a logout request manually from the front end to the auth server instead of letting gateway do this out of the blue and on its own.

I use the RP-Initiated Logout from the OpenID standard: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2 Note than starting from Spring Security 6.4.0, the Back-channel Logout implementation for clients with oauth2Login is finally working, even with cookie-based protection against CSRF and logout+jwt tokens (as Keycloak produces). But neither of the two involve a direct communication from the client to the OP during Logout.
